# How do you check if a record pointer has no value in Object Pascal / Delphi?

Tags: pointers, delphi, pascal

I am trying to create a linked list implementation in Delphi, but can't create a node because I need to check if  the head pointer is empty or not. The code I'm using right now looks like this:

```
procedure LinkedList.addNode(newNode: Node);
var lastNode: Node;
begin
if pHead = nil then
  pHead := @newNode
else
   lastNode := peekLastNode(pHead^);
   lastNode.pNext := @newNode;
end;
```

The program freezes up after just adding one element, so the nil part is the issue indefinitely.

Here is the entire program:

```
program LinkedListImplementation;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;
type
  Node = record
    data: string;
    pNext: ^Node;
  end;
type
  LinkedList = class
    pHead: ^Node;
    function peekLastNode (currentNode: Node) : Node;
    function listToString(currentNode: Node) : String;
    procedure addNode (newNode: Node);
  end;

//the initial parameter for this function is LinkedList.pHead^
function LinkedList.peekLastNode (currentNode: Node) : Node;
begin
  if currentNode.pNext = nil then
    result := currentNode
  else
    result := peekLastNode(currentNode.pNext^);
end;

//produces string in form 'abc -> def -> ghi' from linked list
function LinkedList.listToString(currentNode: Node) : String;
begin
  if currentNode.pNext = nil then
    result := currentNode.data
  else
    result := currentNode.data + ' -> ' + listToString(currentNode.pNext^)
end;

//this uses helper method 'peekLastNode'
procedure LinkedList.addNode(newNode: Node);
var lastNode: Node;
begin
if pHead = nil then
  pHead := @newNode
else
   lastNode := peekLastNode(pHead^);
   lastNode.pNext := @newNode;
end;

var
  Strings: LinkedList;
  String1: Node;
  String2: Node;
begin
  try
    String1.data := 'abc';
    String2.data := 'def';
    Strings.Create();
    Strings.addNode(String1);
    Strings.addNode(String2);

    WriteLn(Strings.listToString(Strings.pHead^));
    ReadLn;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Please add your linked code to your q as text, readers should not have to follow external links to know what you are asking.

Comment: You should use objects, not records.

Comment: Thanks for the lead Olivier. I'm going to do just that and update the post if it works out.

Comment: @Olivier:  Interesting you should say that, but exactly?  Classes have a lot of unnecessary baggage for a task like this, istm.  And Delphi's syntax for classes obscures the problem for a novice, perhaps?  (i.e. you can write code involving class instances without realising that an instance reference is actually a pointer).

Comment: Why do you imagine that using classes would help, if you haven't solved your problem with records?

Comment: @MartynA You need heap allocation for a linked list, and objects are allocated on the heap. Records are not (well it's technically possible to allocate records on the heap, but if you do that, why not use objects instead?).

Comment: Yep did that but it's not running. Tried replacing 'Record' with 'Class' as well as 'Object', but both still caused fatal errors. @Olivier

Comment: @Oliver, I think we will have to agree to differ about that.  It would be far more productive for the OP to learn to debug than to avoid the problem when classes are actually more likely to encourage the sort of problem he's having.

Comment: @neinyards If you just do replaces without understanding what you're doing, it can't work. You must learn the basics of the language first.

Comment: Learn to debug.  You can often debug problems with linked lists just with a pencil and piece of paper - it's often easier to find where your mistaken assumption is than with the IDE debugger.

Comment: @Olivier Yeah I'm not completely familiar with the language yet. Just started yesterday and used whatever documentation I could find to get whatever this is. Usually code in python or vb.net.

Comment: @MartynA Yep I'll give that a shot. Thanks for the help.

Comment: See e.g. http://web.archive.org/web/20120620125356/http://www.learn-programming.za.net:80/programming_pascal_learn14.html.  Btw, for now, stick with records rather than classes - classes will throw no light on this problem, imo.

Comment: @MartynA That code allocates records on the heap with the [`new()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.New) function. It's not harder to write `Class.Create`. At least with objects, you don't need to use `^` everywhere. But I guess it's a matter of preference. Anyway what really matters is to allocate on the heap.

Comment: @Olivier, so?  At least New() is upfront about about what is going on, where object creation isn't.  IAC, with records you don't **need** any allocations at all in extremis, the records could be elements of a static array.  Also IAC, to debug llist code, the question to ask 90+% of the time is "where is my pointer pointing?"  Anyway, end of correspondence, it is going nowhere, istm.

Answer (score 5):

In `addNode()`, if `pHead` is `nil` then you are setting it to point at a local variable, and if it is not `nil` then you set `lastNode.pNext` instead to point at another local variable.  Those local variables go out of scope when `addNode()` exits, thus leaving `pHead`/`pNext` dangling so they are pointing at invalid memory for the next time you try to use them.

You need to use heap allocation when adding `Node` instances to your list, and you need to pass `^Node` pointers around rather than `Node` instances directly.

Also, `addNode()` has a logic error in that it sets `lastNode.pNext` unconditionally whether `pHead` is `nil` or not.  If pHead is `nil` then `lastNode` is not assigned anything. The `else` block is missing `begin..end` statements around its operations.

Also, you are not even constructing the `LinkedList` object correctly.  `Strings.Create();` needs to be `Strings := LinkedList.Create();` instead.

With that said, try something more like this:

```pascal
program LinkedListImplementation;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  PNode = ^Node;
  Node = record
    data: string;
    pNext: PNode;
  end;

type
  LinkedList = class
  private
    pHead: PNode;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function peekLastNode(currentNode: PNode = nil): PNode;
    function listToString(currentNode: PNode = nil): String;
    function addNode(const data: String): PNode;
    procedure clear;
  end;

destructor LinkedList.Destroy;
begin
  clear;
end;

//the initial parameter for this function is LinkedList.pHead
function LinkedList.peekLastNode(currentNode: PNode) : PNode;
begin
  if currentNode = nil then currentNode := pHead;
  if (currentNode = nil) or (currentNode.pNext = nil) then
    Result := currentNode
  else
    Result := peekLastNode(currentNode.pNext);
end;

{ Alternatively:

function LinkedList.peekLastNode(currentNode: PNode): PNode;
begin
  if currentNode = nil then currentNode := pHead;
  Result := currentNode;
  if Result <> nil then
  begin
    while Result.pNext <> nil do
      Result := Result.pNext;
  end;
end;
}

//produces string in form 'abc -> def -> ghi' from linked list
function LinkedList.listToString(currentNode: PNode): String;
begin
  if currentNode = nil then currentNode := pHead;
  if currentNode = nil then
    Result := ''
  else if currentNode.pNext = nil then
    Result := currentNode.data
  else
    Result := currentNode.data + ' -> ' + listToString(currentNode.pNext);
end;

{ Alternatively:

function LinkedList.listToString(currentNode: PNode): String;
begin
  Result := '';
  if currentNode = nil then currentNode := pHead;
  if currentNode <> nil then
  begin
    Result := currentNode.data;
    while currentNode.pNext <> nil do
    begin
      currentNode := currentNode.pNext;
      Result := Result + ' -> ' + currentNode.data;
    end;
  end;
end;
}

//this uses helper method 'peekLastNode'
function LinkedList.addNode(const data: String): PNode;
begin
  New(Result);
  Result.data := data;
  Result.pNext := nil;
  if pHead = nil then
    pHead := Result
  else
    peekLastNode(pHead).pNext := Result;
end;

{ Alternatively:

function LinkedList.addNode(const data: String): PNode;
var
  currentNode: ^PNode;
begin
  currentNode := @pHead;
  while currentNode^ <> nil do
    currentNode := @((currentNode^).pNext);
  New(currentNode^);
  (currentNode^).data := data;
  (currentNode^).pNext := nil;
  Result := currentNode^;
end;
}

procedure LinkedList.clear;
var
  currentNode, nextNode: PNode;
begin
  currentNode := pHead;
  while currentNode <> nil do
  begin
    nextNode := currentNode.pNext;
    Dispose(currentNode);
    currentNode := nextNode;
  end;
end;

var
  Strings: LinkedList;
begin
  try
    Strings := LinkedList.Create();
    try
      Strings.addNode('abc');
      Strings.addNode('def');

      WriteLn(Strings.listToString());
    finally
      Strings.Free();
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: The attention to detail and effort is amazing. Thank you so much for fixing up my program. I'm going to study this program to get a better hang of Delphi and pointers.